# Why can I flag the same question twice?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Just out of curiosity, why can I flag the [same question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33162/how-much-text-is-important-in-a-propsal-document-with-mockups) twice without being informed that I've already flagged this question?

[image]

Comment: I know for a fact you can flag more than once with a stock + custom flag message. Not sure if it lets you use the same stock flag message twice though, I've feared accidentally doing that on another site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions can be flagged several times, yes. However as far as I'm aware this can only happen in the previous flag you raised as already been dealt with (either marked as helpful or declined).

Looking at the flag stats for that question in particular it does appear that your previous flag had already been dealt with before you raised the second one (although it only looks like a matter of seconds between being resolved and the new flag raised, so I may be wrong).

Comment: OK Thanks! I was just curious since it looked "funny".